# Why is Date.today - 6.months + 6.months != Date.today?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, date

In Ruby, on Halloween:

```
Date.today - 6.months + 6.months != Date.today
```

Do we need to update Ruby's date implementation? Do other languages have the same issue?

Comment: It's not a programming language issue, it's a calendar issue.  As long as months do not all have exactly the same number of days (and this is inevitable due to the length of the year), there is no way to make "month arithmetic" work the way other arithmetic does.  The only way to fix this is to adjust the speed at which the Earth travels around the Sun, or to adjust the speed at which the Earth rotates on its axis.

Comment: Is there no ruby gem for fixing Earth speed?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This happens if you do it to any month that doesn't have 31 days (i.e. 3 months would work just fine, but 1 month, or 6, or 8 would all make this happen).

If you do `Date.today - 1.month`, it looks like Rails sees that 9/31/2011 isn't a valid date, so it kicks it back an extra day to make it a valid date. However, when you go one month forward from the end of September, it'll leave it at 10/30/2011 since that's a valid date. Basically, Rails just tries to increment (or decrement) the month field and as long as it's a valid date, it won't adjust the day field.

One way to work around this is to use the `.end_of_month` (or `.beginning_of_month`) method on a `Date` object in Rails to make sure you're consistently getting the end or beginning of a month.

Answer (score 11):

No, this is expected and this isn't unique to Ruby either - try it in SQL, for example.

`(Today - 6 months)` is the last day (30th) of April - because there is no 31st. It's only the months we're dealing with, not a precise number of days.

Add 6 months to April 30th and you get October 30th.

Which, as you know is != October 31st.

Comment: Interesting. It just seems that it could cause problems (actually it did for me).

Answer (score 6):

This is a weird feature of ActiveSupport time extensions.

```
> 6.months == 180.days
=> true
```

but when you do date math with months, they are considered calendar months, not 30-day periods. Check this out:

```
> Date.today - 180.days + 180.days
=> Mon, 31 Oct 2011
```

See https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/calculations.rb#L277 and dig further from there.