# Adding and Subtracting X Months Consistently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, date

I have a Support model that represents an amount of support a user can purchase in our app. It has a starts_at and ends_at attribute, as well as an "amount" that represents the total number of months of support. To keep track of when a user's support expires, we have an attribute on our User model named "support_ends_at".

We've introduced a support gifting feature that allows a user to transfer their remaining support to another user. However, I seem to have run into a problem with this as is highlighted in the following scenario:

- User1 purchases one 6 month Support. Today is Jan 25, 2014 so their support now ends on July 25, 2014.
- User1 purchases a second 6 month Support to gift to a friend. Their support used to end on July 25, 2014 and now ends at Jan 25, 2015.
- User1 gifts their second 6 month Support to User2. Since a little bit of the Support was used, the difference between Support#ends_at and Time.now is taken to get the remaining amount of support. This remainder is subtracted from User1 and given to User2.
- User1's support_ends_at attribute is now set to July 28, 2014. They've somehow gained 3 extra days of support.

This seems to be related to the fact that not every month has the same number of days. So subtracting the remainder is going to get a different amount then it may have if it was taken from the original Support User1 had.

I've looked at [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957107/why-is-date-today-6-months-6-months-date-today) and I realize this is an intentional behavior. I am wondering though, are there are any best practices for dealing with this type of problem? Has anybody come up with a solution they would like to share? It would be much appreciated-- this has been stumping me for a couple of days now.

Comment: How about expressing the support period in days instead of months?

Comment: how are you subtracting the months?