# 1.year.from_now is also one day ahead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Today's date is 2016-09-19. I add one year to it, and I expect the result to be 2017-09-19. Instead, I get 2017-09-20. One year plus one day ahead. Is this behavior as intended?

```
$ rails c
2.3.1 :001 > Time.now.to_date.iso8601
 => "2016-09-19" 
2.3.1 :002 > 1.year.from_now.to_date.iso8601
 => "2017-09-20"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957107/why-is-date-today-6-months-6-months-date-today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`since`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.7.1/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html#method-i-since) or its alias `from_now` calculate the offset based on `Time.current` which is equivalent to `Time.zone.now` – both return a `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` instance:

```
Time.current  #=> Mon, 19 Sep 2016 19:56:34 SST -11:00
Time.zone.now #=> Mon, 19 Sep 2016 19:56:35 SST -11:00
```

`Time.now` on the other hand returns an ordinary `Time` instance in your system's timezone, which can differ from the Rails timezone:

```
Time.now #=> 2016-09-20 08:56:36 +0200
```

To avoid confusion, you should always use `Time.current` / `Time.zone.now` when working within Rails. You can however pass another "base time" to `since`:

```
1.year.since(Time.now) #=> 2017-09-20 08:56:37 +0200
```

Or, because you are working with dates:

```
1.year.since(Date.today) #=> Wed, 20 Sep 2017
```

There is also `Date.current` which is equivalent to `Time.zone.today`:

```
1.year.since(Date.current) #=> Wed, 19 Sep 2017
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want get ecactly date with time zones, you can use `Time.current`

```
1.year.from_now
#=> Wed, 20 Sep 2017 05:38:50 UTC +00:00
Time.current
#=> Tue, 20 Sep 2016 05:39:08 UTC +00:00
```

Comment: It seems that I also need to configure my timezone in my config. Is it better to do everything in UTC?

Comment: Yea, you should set your time zone, but it's not hard ( i edited my post ) :)  Even if you didn't do that, you always get exactly differences from your calculations between your methods.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it's a timezone thing. I'm UTC -7 hours.

`Time.now` returns the time in my timezone.

`1.year.from_now` returns the time in UTC+0, 7 hours ahead of where I am.

It's 10pm here, so it's the next day at UTC+0.